PowerPoint Staying Open after Creation
VBA script in an Excel form is used to create a title page in PowerPoint. Everything is working but the presentation stays open and the code errors-out with the .Quit command. EDIT: Code works as edited below...
Dim PPTM_App As Object
Dim PPTM_File As Object
Set PPTM_App = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPTM_File = PPTM_App.Presentations.Open(folder_path & uen & ".pptm")

    With PPTM_File.Slides(1)
        .Shapes("Title_Txt").OLEFormat.Object = project_text & ": " & product_text
        .Shapes("Sub_Txt").OLEFormat.Object = purpose_text
        .Shapes("ELN_Txt").OLEFormat.Object = uen
        .Shapes("Date_Txt").OLEFormat.Object = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
        .Shapes("Conc_Txt").OLEFormat.Object = "Example text."
    End With
    
PPTM_File.Save 'works
'PPTM_App.Quit 'does not quit - file stays open
PPTM_File.Close

Dim BruteForce As String
BruteForce = "TASKKILL /F /IM powerpnt.exe"
Shell BruteForce, vbHid
    
Set PPTM_File = Nothing
Set PPTM_App = Nothing


Try making PPT visible and see if there is (eg) a dialog preventing it from closing.

Saving takes time, so the Quit command may be firing before the presentation has finished saving. Search on Wait, Sleep and DoEvents to find methods of pausing your code to allow an I/O process to complete.

I added a timer between .Save and .Quit. The timer is running and now the code does not error-out. But the PowerPoint presentation is still staying open.

Add PPTM_File.Close after the Save  ?  Are you seeing any clues after making PPT visible ?

Had to add a brute force kill command.  `PPTM_Doc1.Save
PPTM_Doc1.Close
Dim BruteForce As String
BruteForce = "TASKKILL /F /IM powerpnt.exe"
Shell BruteForce, vbHid`


Although ....Object =... might work (probably using a default property), it doesn't feel right or at least isn't that readable. While your BruteForce hack might close PowerPoint, it won't tell you if the file was saved (probably not). I wrote a more reasonable hack (I guess it's hack time), actually two in one, based on the fact that your file possibly isn't 'ready' to be saved so when the error occurs, PowerPoint stays open. By your description of the behavior, it is a long shot but If you could share your complete code, I would give it a try. Modify any sensitive data.

@TimWilliams In MS365, I played around with it for a while. I came to the conclusion that when you add a new presentation, PPT becomes visible no matter what. If you try to make it invisible, an error occurs so I'm expecting the same behavior when opening a presentation. It seems it is impossible to have multiple instances of PPT open. Also, Excel seems to 'lose focus' so the (multiple) use of AppActivate Application.Caption is necessary. It looks like PPT wasn't meant to be controlled by Excel. Please correct me (obviously a noob) if I'm wrong.

@VBasic2008 If you want to open a presentation (or create a new one) without showing the window, just set the optional WithWindow property of the Presentation.Open (or Presentation.Add) method to msoFalse: Set PPTM_File = PPTM_App.Presentations.Open(folder_path & uen & ".pptm", WithWindow:=msoFalse) or SetPPTM_File = PPTM_App.Presentations.Add(msoFalse)

@Chronocidal Gold! I forgot to look that up in the Docs. Unbelievable. Do you have a link to a good tutorial (text or video)? I had my share of Docs for today.

VBA will not let you programmatically close PowerPoint while there are still Memory Pointers/References to it active.
In other words, you cannot run PPTM_App.Quit until after you Set PPTM_File = Nothing.  You do not need to have run PPTM_File.Close before this: if the file formerly known as PPTM_File is still open, then PPTM_App.Quit will cause it to close.
VBA does not care about whether the file is open or closed, it only cares about whether it still has the file assigned to an Object variable.
(Well, you can run PPTM_App.Quit before then, but it will just try to queue the command until there are no more active Pointers/References — such as after the current Subroutine ends and automatically frees up your Object variables)
So, either the following codes will work:
PPTM_File.Save
Set PPTM_File = Nothing
PPTM_App.Quit
Set PPTM_App= Nothing

'OR

PPTM_File.Save
PPTM_File.Close
Set PPTM_File = Nothing
PPTM_App.Quit
Set PPTM_App = Nothing

While both of these will exhibit the error you are experiencing:
PPTM_File.Save
PPTM_App.Quit
Set PPTM_App= Nothing

'OR

PPTM_File.Save
PPTM_File.Close
PPTM_App.Quit
Set PPTM_App = Nothing

because, in both cases, there is still an active reference to PPTM_File in Memory.

To my knowledge, the only thing that is true is the sentence starting with You do not need to... stating that there is no need to close the file since it has just been saved. How did you come up with the rest of it? I've seen similar statements online and coming from ChatGPT. Hopefully, you can provide some relevant links e.g. to the docs.

@VBasic2008 It's something I've learned from experience and debugging.  It's observed (and repeatable) empirical results, rather than something from the documentation.  For example, if you run PPTM_File.Save: PPTM_App.Quit: DoEvents: Application.Wait(Now()+TimeSerial(0,5,0)): Beep: Set PPTM_File = Nothing then you will be able to observe that it does not close PowerPoint until after the 5 minute wait elapses and the Pointer is freed.

Thanks for sharing. Sorry for bothering but could you share some insights on the 2nd comment I posted in OP's comments.
